# Deploy phase failed can't see s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am using the AWS console codepipeline wizard. I got nearly to the end, but the last step, the DEPLOY step gives me an error:

Action execution failed

Invalid action configuration
The action failed because either the artifact or the Amazon S3 bucket could not be found. Name of artifact bucket: codepipeline-us-east-1-846341676998. Verify that this bucket exists. If it exists, check the life cycle policy, then try releasing a change.

I think it can't see my S3 bucket due to permissions. Who do I give access permissions to? I tried many different roles to give S3 access to but couldn't find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

If it fails at deploy stage, make sure the role used in Code Deploy has access to the S3 bucket you mentioned. You can create a new policy and attach it to the role.
I assume you are using Code Deploy in Code Pipeline for deployments.